# How to split progress bar for multi processes happening simultaneously

Tags: wpf

I am having multiple heavy processes happening simultaneously  , i am so confused as how to show the progress for each process in a single progress bar. as i saw in software like Torrent , they splits  the progress bar for multiple processes . Could you please help me to create progress bar like that ? i have telerik progress bar also in my hand .

any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding you have already created those many progress bars for the individual processes, you just want to have one that summarizes them all up into one.

If that's the case you could have attach an event handler to each of the processes' progress report change, and when that handler is notified, set that property to:

```
var count = allProcesses.Count;
var all = allProcesses.Sum(p => p.Progress);
//You could replace the following with max = count * 100 if that's the case
var max = allProcesses.Sum(p => p.Max); 
overallProgressBar.Minimum = 0;
overallProgressBar.Maximum = max;
overallProgressBar.Value = all;
```

Note: assuming `0-100` is the progress range for all processes.

Comment: This way you assume all jobs are equal in needed effort.

Comment: @Erno, it doesn't make any difference once you have the data for the individual processes. I've updated my answer.

Comment: That is not what I meant. You assume that 100 progress in job A is equal to 100 progress in job B.

Comment: @Erno, wrong. In my updated example the so called 100 is individual per process.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single ProgressBar for each process (that is easiest)

To use a single ProgressBar for all processes you'll need to calculate the entire effort first and then have each process report its progression to the entire progress.

Example

2 processes: Process A is reading 2000 records and Process B is reading 6000 records.
To calculate the overall progress:

```
progress = (2000/(2000 + 6000)) * (progressA / 2000) + 
           (6000/(2000 + 6000)) * (progressB / 6000);
```

In general:

```
totalProgress = sum for all progresses (totalEffortA/totalEffort) * (progressA / totalEffortA)
```